# ag-grid Cannot set focused cell in ngOnInit

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to set the focus to the first editable cell in my grid and am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFocusedCell' of undefined".

I'm calling setFocusedCell in ngOnInit in my ag-grid-angular component. Here is a snippet:

```
constructor(private mcService: MonteCarloService) {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        rowData: MCInputGridComponent.createRowData(),
        columnDefs: MCInputGridComponent.createColumnDefs()
    };
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setFocusedCell(1, "histDataType", null);
}
```

I've defined the columns and set some data via the constructor methods. Below are the column definitions.

```
private static createColumnDefs() {
    return [
        {
            colKey: "sprint#",
            headerName: "Sprint #",
            field: "sprint",
            width: 80,
            editable: false
        },
        {
            colKey: "histDataType",
            headerName: "Velocity",
            field: "histDataType",
            cellEditorFramework: NumericEditorComponent,
            editable: true,
            width: 102
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling setFocusedCell in ngOnInit, call it in onGridReady (gridReady)